# When to use a Visual Studio Project for a Layer in a Layered Architecture? What are the benefits for physical seperation?

Tags: architecture, n-layer

Today I discussed a software architecture topic with my co-worker. We don't know why most examples for layered software architecture uses a separate Visual Studio Project? What are disadvantages of logical separating the layers into Visual Studio Projects? Our team consist of 4 to 6 software developers.

Comment: Please confine/edit your question to a higher standard for stack overflow..

Comment: Interesting question. I am also interested on this kind of architecture design questions. I would prefer physical seperation but I cannot explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also asking myself the same question when starting a new project...

In my opinion:

**Separation in Visual Studio Projects** has the benefits:

- that you do not need to recompile projects that have not been changed. In large projects this may lead to faster compilation times.
- you can reuse several components by including a former compiled DLL in a different project. E.g. something like a Framework DLL or some core component you develop in each project.
- thinking of large projects: several teams work on several projects: If all the people would just use one project you would have a huge load of merge conflicts when you would just work on a single Project

Comment: I agree with your first two arguments. Concerning your third argument: You can achieve Seperation of Concern with corresponding project folders too. Therefore you can avoid merging conflicts. This is not suitable for large teams but maybe for smaller ones. Another advantage for using seperate Projects/DLL for a layer would be scalibility. You can install the DLL on different machines and scale them up on demand.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the video ['Creating N-Tier Application in C#](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/n-tier-apps-part1)' today from Steve Smith on Pluralsight. This video helped me to find the right answer for me. When you logically seperate your application into layers but combine them physically into a single assembly, the main advantages are simple deployment and performance.

You gain performance because you have no machine and process boundaries. The deployment is simple because you can deploy a single artefact of your build.

The physicall seperation of the architecture into layers is the first step before the application can be deployed in a different manner. Furthermore you can apply Service Oriented Architecture with physical separation.